# ActiveMQ Artemis: CORE management API and hawtio issue

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-artemis

I am using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.19.1 with the **CORE Management API** (`org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client.*`, and `org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.management.*`) to get the **consumer counts** from some prefixed queues. If the counts are equal to zero there is something done in the back-end. This is done by a scheduled task which asks the broker periodically for this information.

For each request a temporary address is created under the hood and after consuming the info it is then deleted.

The problem is that the tree of the Artemis/Hawtio web console keeps refreshing making the UI sluggish and it's not maintainable.
There is also [a hint from Hawtio](https://hawtio.github.io/hawtio/faq/index.html) already regarding this behavior (see the subsection titled "The tree keeps refreshing making the UI sluggish").

As far as I know the CORE api is able to handle different nodes of a cluster which is way much more effort as with Jolokia. I think this was the main reason for using it.

Is there another possibility to handle this? Maybe some kind of connection/ session pooling?  Or can the broker communicate with backend if the consumer count is zero? Or maybe the temporary queues could be deleted in a batch instead of each at a time?

This is what the logs say again and again:

```
[org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl] AMQ841007: created queue: QueueImpl[name=activemq.management.96a1005f-b67c-40af-b9cd-811f36750c5e, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=artemis-2.19.1], temp=true]@58d1994e

[org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.plugin.impl] AMQ841008: destroyed queue: QueueImpl[name=activemq.management.96a1005f-b67c-40af-b9cd-811f36750c5e, postOffice=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=artemis-2.19.1], temp=true]@58d1994e, with args address: activemq.management.96a1005f-b67c-40af-b9cd-811f36750c5e, session: ServerSessionImpl(), checkConsumerCount: true, removeConsumers: false, autoDeleteAddress: true
```

For the connection I am using following:

```java
private ServerLocator locator;
private ClientSessionFactory defaultFactory;

public ManagementHelper(String defaultURL) {
    this.locator = ActiveMQClient.createServerLocator(defaultURL);
    this.defaultFactory = locator.createSessionFactory();
}
```

```java
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "20000")
public void getConsumerNbos(ClientSessionFactory factory, ServerLocator locator) {
    try (ClientSession session = factory.createSession(this.username, this.password, false, true, true,
            locator.isPreAcknowledge(), locator.getAckBatchSize());
            ClientRequestor requestor = new ClientRequestor(session, "activemq.management");) {

        ClientMessage message = session.createMessage(false);
        ManagementHelper.putOperationInvocation(message, ResourceNames.BROKER, listAllConsumersAsJSON);
        session.start();

        ClientMessage replyConsumer = requestor.request(message);
        String resultJSON = (String) ManagementHelper.getResult(replyConsumer, String.class);

        ClientMessage message2 = session.createMessage(false);
        ManagementHelper.putOperationInvocation(message2, ResourceNames.BROKER, MANAGEMENT_OPERATION_QUEUES);

        ClientMessage replyQueueNames = requestor.request(message2);
        Object[] objQueueNames = (Object[]) ManagementHelper.getResult(replyQueueNames);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Comment: @jbertram Thank you Justin, for your recommendation, it makes it at least better. Anyway, the deletion of any other temporary queues/ addresses also causes a lot of reloading, means a collapse of the whole treeview. In general, how is it meant to be used then? Or it seems to be a hawtio issue?

Comment: Is there a possibility to cache consumer connections for temporary queues from UI for example, to avoid ActiveMQ adding/ removing mbeans with each connection?

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, the log indicates that a *queue* is being created and destroyed, not an address.

The queue is being created an destroyed because you're using a `org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client.ClientRequestor`. When you create a `ClientRequestor` it automatically creates a temporary queue named with a UUID on the address which you indicate (e.g. `activemq.management` in your case). Then when you close the `ClientRequestor` it deletes this queue.

My recommendation would be to simply cache your `ClientSession` and your `ClientRequestor` just like you do for your `ServerLocator` and `ClientSessionFactory`, e.g.:

```java
private ServerLocator locator;
private ClientSessionFactory defaultFactory;
private ClientSession session;
private ClientRequestor requestor;

public ManagementHelper(String defaultURL) {
    this.locator = ActiveMQClient.createServerLocator(defaultURL);
    this.defaultFactory = locator.createSessionFactory();
    this.session = factory.createSession(this.username, this.password, false, true, true, locator.isPreAcknowledge(), locator.getAckBatchSize());
    this.requestor = new ClientRequestor(session, "activemq.management");
}
```

```java
@Scheduled(fixedRateString = "20000")
public void getConsumerNbos(ClientSessionFactory factory, ServerLocator locator) {
    ClientMessage message = session.createMessage(false);
    ManagementHelper.putOperationInvocation(message, ResourceNames.BROKER, listAllConsumersAsJSON);
    session.start();

    ClientMessage replyConsumer = requestor.request(message);
    String resultJSON = (String) ManagementHelper.getResult(replyConsumer, String.class);

    ClientMessage message2 = session.createMessage(false);
    ManagementHelper.putOperationInvocation(message2, ResourceNames.BROKER, MANAGEMENT_OPERATION_QUEUES);

    ClientMessage replyQueueNames = requestor.request(message2);
    Object[] objQueueNames = (Object[]) ManagementHelper.getResult(replyQueueNames);
}
```

If you are still having issues with the Hawtio refresh then you can also disable it by going to the "Preferences" page (in the top right of the web console) and clicking on the "Jolokia" tab and changing the "Update rate" to "Off". Here's a screenshot of the page:
[image: Jolokia Preferences]

Comment: I think I was able to reproduce the problem now: Apparently, it depends on which level of the tree you have clicked on, means which is marked pink. If you expand the "addresses" level just with the left angle (not the word) - it's not going to be marked pink, it's just expanding the tree. The pink mark stays at level 0, if it was there before. If  then a new mbean is loaded, the tree collapses, showing only level 0 and 1. Instead: If you expand "addresses" and also mark it pink, a created or removed mbean does not collapse the tree.