# HawtIO ActiveMQ table refresh rate

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, apache-karaf, hawtio

I'm running HawtIO (version 2.14.3) within Apache Karaf.

I very frequently use the ActiveMQ table view to inspect the queue sizes etc.
In this version however, the table refreshes so fast that it's hard to use.
It goes like:

1. Blank screen for 2 seconds
2. Display the table for 0.5 seconds
3. Blank screen for 2 seconds
4. and repeat...

Is there a way to set the refresh interval(or maybe disable it entirely)?
I know that in older versions of HawtIO this was a setting in the UI.

[image: HawtIO ActiveMQ table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out jbertram's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73697032/17377539) on disable web console refreshing. Probably it's the same setting for you.